# can i use pivot for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this is the table structure

```
   id   empRef_ID   mkt_route_ID    sl_No
----------------------------------------------------
    1     8            6              1
    2     8            8              1
    3     8            20             2
    4     8            22             2
    5     8            23             2
```

and i want out put like this

```
    empRef_ID   mkt_route_ID    sl_No
----------------------------------------------------
      8            6/8            1
      8            20/22/23       2
```

Comment: No, this is not a job for PIVOT but rather for a [SQL Server equivalent of MySQL GROUP_CONCAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005 "Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?").

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT empRef_ID , mkt_route_ID=  
    STUFF((SELECT '/ ' + cast(mkt_route_ID as varchar)
           FROM table_2 b 
           WHERE b.sl_No = a.sl_No 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),sl_No 
FROM table_2 a
GROUP BY empRef_ID,sl_No
```