# Append results of a query in a single line

Tags: sql, informix, 4gl

I am unloading the results of a query to a file. I need the result records to be displayed in a single line. For example,

```
unload to file.unl select col from table where col = "test";
```

The resulting file.unl would be like

```
test|
test|
....
test|
```

But what I would like to get is,

```
test|test|test|....|test|
```

Any guidance or ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/11356573/1216425

Comment: @teran: Can you explain the **FOR XML PATH ..** is necessary in 4gl?

Comment: sorry, I didn't note that you are using 4gl. answer above is for MS SQL;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably aware you can declare `DELIMITER "|"` in the SQL or via the DBDELIMITER environment variable. As far as I know, there is no way to change the default **record** terminator from `NEWLINE` to anything else.

So I suspect you will need to either write a custom function that iterates through the results and appends them to a variable which you then write out to a file, or write a separate piece of script that you call via `RUN` that pivots the data from rows to columns, eg:

```
UNLOAD TO file.unl SELECT col FROM table WHERE ...;    
RUN "/usr/bin/perl -ni -e 'chomp; print' file.unl";
```

I've assumed you're running on Unix and have perl handy. If you don't, you might find the iterator suggestion more practical than mucking about with installing perl on Windows, particularly if you have limited control over machines this code gets run on.

**Update**

My 4GL is very rusty, but I was decribing something very basic, eg:

```
DEFINE command CHAR(10100)
DEFINE long_string CHAR(10000)
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT col FROM table WHERE ...

FOREACH curs1 INTO col1
    LET long_string = long_string CLIPPED || col1 CLIPPED || '|'
END FOREACH
LET command = "echo '" || long_string CLIPPED || "' > file.unl"
RUN command
```

It's 15 years or more since I wrote any 4GL, so treat that as pseudo-code at most, please. There might be a better way to write directly to a file, I honestly can't remember.

Comment: I have been using Perl for a while. Is there a way to accomplish this without using scripts?

Comment: Updated answer with simple iterator example. I still think the perl version is better; it's both less code and less susceptible to mangling by accidental shell interpretation.

Comment: I've fixed up the I4GL code a bit.  The Perl mechanism, flattening all but the very last newline would the way to go; the I4GL code is delicate and vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: An HPL or UNLOAD option for defining or suppressing the end of record marker would be desirable!

Answer (score 1):

CREATE Table #Table (
    PKey INT Primary key,
    Field VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Table
select 1, 'ABS1' UNION ALL
select 2, 'ABS2' UNION ALL
select 3, 'ABS3'

DECLARE @results VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

select 
    @results = COALESCE(
        @results + '|' + Field, 
        @results
    )
from #Table

SELECT @results

Comment: What language is this?? Why are you using @ before results? Please explain.

Comment: This is a sql query. The @ before the results means that I am creating a varchar variable to concatenate all my results into. I finally select that variable as my results.

Comment: @Sarah: Thank you for explaining.. Please understand that I am using Informix-4GL for querying.

Comment: I understand, it looked very similar to sql.

Comment: The `@` and `#` notation is MS SQL Server (or possibly Sybase) and very little to do with Informix-4GL.